# Insert a property from a JavaScript object into a string

Tags: javascript

Why js window.location is not accept a variable that assigned from json,
I hava checked my json, and the json is exist by console.log(myJsonCallback)

```
 Object { status=1,  action="update",  id=90}
```

The code like this,

```
if(response.action === "update"){ 
   var id = response.id;window.location.href=
       "/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fview&id=id"}
```

in browser, little funny coz it gives me :

```
http://10.60.36.79/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fview&id=id
```

Please advice

**UPDATE**

My original code like this :

```
. 'if(response.action === "update"){'
   . ' var id = response.id;'
   . 'window.location.href= "' . Url::toRoute(['view']) . '&id=${id}"'
  . '}'
```

See, I use dot(.) cos the code is a string on php

Please advice

Comment: FYI, that's not json, it's a Javascript object. They are not the same thing

Answer (score 4):

If what you expected to work would actually interpolate the variable, it would look like this:

```
/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fview&90=90
```

But your string does not actually contain any variables. Try this instead:

```
if(response.action === "update") {
  var id = response.id;
  window.location.href = "/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fview&id=" + id;
}
```

Or if you are using ES6, you can use template literals

```
window.location.href = `/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fview&id=${id}`;
```

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `"/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fview&id=id"`, this entire line is a single string without any variable. You will have to concatenate this string with the actual id.

Like this :

```
if(response.action === "update"){ 
    var id = response.id;
    window.location.href = "/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fview&id=" + id ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, my bad,
Perhaps not sleep until morning today.

this is the code

```
   . 'if(response.action === "update"){'
        . ' var id = response.id;'
        . 'window.location.href= "' . Url::toRoute(['view']) . '&id=" + id'
   . '}'
```

Please, up again